# python tornado queue toro task consuming in parallel

Tags: python, asynchronous, parallel-processing, queue, tornado

Could anyone be so kind and let me know how to run long running tasks in parallel? here is my solution, with sequential solution:

https://gist.github.com/dzizes/4c23ba4c2cd7bfbeff643c0cb85749c7

Comment: What's your question? Is there something wrong with the gist you presented that you need help with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start multiple workers. This line starts one worker coroutine:

```
io_loop.run_sync(mongoQueue.worker)
```

Instead, do something like:

```
@gen.coroutine
def workers(self):
    futures = [self.worker() for _ in range(CONCURRENT)]
    yield futures
```

Then:

```
io_loop.run_sync(mongoQueue.workers)
```

I'd move the job of filling the queue out of the workers and put it in producers instead:

```
@gen.coroutine
def producer(self):
    while self.running:
        yield self.load_work()
```

This more closely resembles [the standard consumer-producer code in the Tornado docs](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/queues.html#tornado.queues.Queue). Then, update `workers` so it spawns a producer:

```
@gen.coroutine
def workers(self):
    IOLoop.current().spawn_callback(self.producer)
    futures = [self.worker() for _ in range(CONCURRENT)]
    yield futures
```

See [the docs for why we use spawn_callback to spawn a coroutine](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/coroutines.html#how-to-call-a-coroutine). You'll need to set self.running True at the start, and decide when to end your producer by setting self.running False. You also need to decide how to end the worker coroutines.

A couple other corrections to your code. First, don't confuse yourself by naming a coroutine with the value `_thread`: your code is single-threaded and it achieves concurrency using coroutines. Second, you don't need `gen.sleep`, the max queue size will throttle the producer.

Comment: it is really helpfull. I did adapt gist, please take a look: https://gist.github.com/dzizes/4c23ba4c2cd7bfbeff643c0cb85749c7

I'm not sure where to set self.running correctly. producer/load_work() should work constantly - jobs (inserts to db) are comming from another application:

it looks now that producer produces all jobs (7) and consumer consumes jobs (7) and so on

Comment: Set self.running = True at the start of your application, and set self.running = False when it's time for your application to exit.

Comment: but I do not end application. it works like a deamon. when I run it without sleep it consumes full CPU.

Comment: What I actually need is a deamon, which will consume jobs from db and process then in parallel (not concurent). Is it possible to achive it with Tornado?